# Change the created site category on Area 51

Tags: discussion, area-51

I've just created a site on Area 51 and realized that I had set the wrong category, but realized that I couldn't change it with editing.

Is the only way to delete the site and create it again tomorrow?

Comment: @animuson The answer there is to post on Area 51 Discussions. However, I'm not sure how often the site is actually monitored by staff, given that flags I raised there have sat unhandled for very long times.